# Can I uninstall the Intel graphics driver if an Nvidia GPU is present?

Tags: windows-8, gpu, intel-graphics

I have a Dell XPS15 laptop, which includes a Geforce GT750M GPU. Ever since I updated the Nvidia driver to 347.25, I've been getting errors from `igfxtray.exe` on startup. Google tells me that this file is part of the driver suite for the integrated Intel GPU.

As far as I can tell, everything still works fine despite this file not working. Since I have no intention of ever using the crapsack Intel GPU, and I'd rather not have an error dialog appear every time I boot up, will it be ok if I uninstall the driver? I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro.

---

This is the error dialog box that pops up. If I can't uninstall the driver, can I at least get it not to load the system tray module?

[image]

Comment: Since you already installed a driver that doesn't have the capability of switching between the two devices you might as well uninstall it since having it installed does you not good.  Of course you also are unlikely to have the current version of the Intel driver installed so you can also just try installing that.  You might be shocked to learn that the Intel GPU isn't all that bad compared to your dedicated GPU.

Comment: @Ramhound I decided to bite the bullet and uninstall the Intel driver. After I rebooted, nothing bad happened, except I noticed I couldn't change the screen resolution anymore. I can live with that, I thought... but then Windows up and reinstalled the darn driver for me! Still, the error seems to have gone away, touch wood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`igfxtray` is responsible for the notification area icon of Intel's display driver. It's not an essential component of the driver suite. The actual driver is still working.

Furthermore, you're using the Intel GPU all the time, even when NVIDIA GPU is enabled to be always-on. Here's a part of my answer to a [different question](https://superuser.com/q/872099/194694):

> First off, your laptop doesn't actually have two complete graphics cards. It has two GPUs, but only one is completely wired and all outputs are connected to it. This is true for most laptops with hybrid NVIDIA graphics.
>
> Your laptop's main graphics card is Intel HD Graphics 4000, which is integrated in the CPU. It's always enabled and it's the only device in your laptop that can produce video signal on outputs. When a graphics-intensive application is running, NVIDIA GPU kicks in and starts rendering graphics. Then pre-rendered frames are sent to Intel GPU and it forwards them to outputs. For Intel GPU these are just still images and it's quite good at rendering them, so there's no performance loss.

I don't know what exactly would happen if you uninstall the Intel driver, but I'm pretty sure nothing good.

Since you haven't provided exact error messages that you're seeing (these are always important, error messages almost always describe the culprit) I can only recommend updating your drivers. Just click the *Update Drivers* button on [Intel's website](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/) and follow on-screen instructions.

If this doesn't help, please provide error messages in question.

Comment: Based on the drivers he already has installed its very unlikely his system can even switch between the two devices currently.  That capability is normally only enabled and possible when the OEM display drivers are installed.

Comment: @Ramhound Why do you think so? As I understand it, both Intel and NVIDIA drivers are currently installed, but Intel's tray interface doesn't work since last NVIDIA update.

Comment: I don't think so because the drivers for mobile devices that `Nvidia` distributes does not normally enable the feature that allows the seamless switching between the two devices.  There were also very recent updates to Intel's drivers ( in the last week ) that the user made no mention of installing.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm using these drivers since 3 years or so and all the time I've been able to choose which GPU I want to use per-app and system-wide. I'm using version 340.52 right now and this feature is present. http://i.stack.imgur.com/EKQLf.png

Comment: You found those drivers from Nvidia directly?  I guess the landscape has changed.  I was almost certain the Nvidia/AMD feature that enabled this was only enabled in the drivers released by the mobile device's OEM itself.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, these are generic NVIDIA drivers. I have never used OEM drivers on this OS.

Comment: @Ramhound the 347.25 drivers also have this feature. gronostaj: I used the link you provided, but the Intel driver update tool said I had a OEM-customised driver. Checking on the Dell website also didn't reveal any updates.

Comment: Uninstall the Intel drivers then;  The device will work without them until you can install them

Comment: @Ramhound I'd rather wait until I've exhausted the other options, like just disabling igfxtray.exe, given what gronostaj has posted. However now I can't find igfxtray in the startup options anywhere....