# Maximum available resolution is 1080x1920 when connecting UHD monitor using hdmi

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, 4k-resolution

I just purchased a 4k Samsung Monitor (Samsung u28d590ds), and the problem is that when I connect to my laptop through hdmi the maximum available resolution is 1080x1920.
From what I understood is that I should be able to output 4k at 30 hz using the high speed hdmi cable that was provided with the monitor.

Laptop Hardware:
Nvidia Geforce Gt 650m 2 gb
Intel core i7 3630 qm with integrated intel HD 4000 graphics

I tried updating the drivers of the intel and nvidia graphics adapters, but the problem is still persisting.

Comment: You tried updating the drivers or you did update the drivers?  What version of HDMI cable are you using?  your Nvidia and Intel GPU should have no problem doing this.

Comment: I updated to the latest drivers and using the HDMI cable supplied with the monitor which has ethernet, so I guess it's at least version 1.4

Comment: Is it possible that the limitation could come from HMDI output, or does HDMI output have the same limitation as the graphics card?

Comment: Your monitor supports 4k.  Both GPUs in your system supports 4k.  The problem likely is a display driver problem honestly.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to a similar but not identical problem.

I bought a video card (PNY) with NVIDIA GeForce GT 730, connected by HDMI to a Samsung U28E590D 4k capable monitor.  Windows 7 x64.

The NVIDIA Control Panel -> Change resolution screen shows HDMI - HDTV, and Ultra HD, but only with maximum resolution  "1920x1080 (recommended)".

The Windows Screen resolution application: 
(Mouse right on desktop)->Screen resolution application 
is showing only 1920 x 1080.

I tried installing the Samsung driver from the CD that comes with the monitor, no help.

What finally worked was this.

NVIDIA Control Panel -> Change resolution -> Customize...
then
Create Custom Resolution...
then
Display mode
Horizontal pixels: 3840 
Vertical pixels: 2160
Refresh rate(Hz): 30.

Then,  *IMPORTANT*
change the timing from Automatic to one of the other choices.  I think the best choice is "CVT reduced blank".

Automatic timing gives a very fuzzy screen.  But one of the other timings apparently tell the video card to use native resolution correctly.

Aside 1:
In the course of chatting with NVIDIA support, they pointed me at a tool that will show you what your monitor is telling your computer about its resolution and color capabilities:
http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/moninfo.shtm

Aside 2:
This monitor is only 28".  Full 4k resolution is very tiny. So I ended up creating a custom resolution of 2560 x 1440, 60Hz.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have the same monitor and graphics card. Oddly, it doesn't appear to have saved the custom resolutions after a reboot. You're right in that 4K makes everything tiny doing it this way, but you can set Windows 10 to scale the text to 150% which makes it much better - that way you get the benefit of extra pixels but the text is far more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a dual graphics configuration Nvidia GT650m + Intel HD 4000, first change the preferred graphics processor in the NVIDIA Control Panel.

NVIDIA Control Panel -> Manage 3D Settings -> Preferred Graphics Processor.

Change it to "High performance NVIDIA processor".

Then plugin your HDMI cable and see if there is an option for 4K resolution under Change resolution in your NVIDIA Control Panel. See if this helps.

There are some who are facing the same kind of issue with 4K resolution having this kind of dual graphics configuration in their laptop.

Comment: Video outputs are always driven by Intel GPU, see [my answer here](http://superuser.com/a/872110/194694).

Comment: I have already tried doing this, but the maximum resolution is still at 1080p.

Comment: @GeoHotz - You have the current [intel](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=3rd+Generation+Intel%c2%ae+Core%e2%84%a2+Processors+with+Intel%c2%ae+HD+Graphics+4000) drivers installed?